# PUB/SUB pattern in ZeroMQ not working

Tags: go, zeromq, distributed-system

I am trying to implement a very basic **`PUB/SUB`** pattern using ZeroMQ. I would like to have a server (always active) broadcasting messages (publisher) to all clients and does not care about connected clients.
If a clients connect to this server as a subscriber, it should receive the message.

However, I can not send the message using `PUB/SUB`.

In Python it would be:

```
# publisher (server.py)
import zmq

ctx = zmq.Context()
publisher = ctx.socket(zmq.PUB)
publisher.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:9091')

while True:
    publisher.send_string("test")
```

and

```
# subscriber (client.py)
import zmq

ctx = zmq.Context()
subscriber = ctx.socket(zmq.SUB)
subscriber.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:9091')

while True:
    msg = subscriber.recv_string()
    print msg
```

Or in golang:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/pebbe/zmq4"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func Listen(subscriber *zmq4.Socket) {
    for {
        s, err := subscriber.Recv(0)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        log.Println("rec", s)
    }
}

func main() {
    publisher, _ := zmq4.NewSocket(zmq4.PUB)
    defer publisher.Close()
    publisher.Bind("tcp://*:9090")

    subscriber, _ := zmq4.NewSocket(zmq4.SUB)
    defer subscriber.Close()
    subscriber.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:9090")

    go Listen(subscriber)
    for _ = range time.Tick(time.Second) {
        publisher.Send("test", 0)
        log.Println("send", "test")

    }
}
```

Did I mis-understood this pattern or do I need to send a particular signal from the client to the server, when connecting. I am interested in the golang version and only use the python version for testing.

Comment: you must check for errors prior any debuging steps. I have not used zmq myself, although, the call to bind, with that address smell bad from here. I might be wrong, checking for errors should give clues.

Comment: @mh-cbon No, sir, the `.Bind()` on the `PUB`-side is absolutely not a problem. The devil is in details, in the subscription management ( primary issue ) and in avoiding infinite deadlocks ( using a `.SetLinger( 0 )` method on all socket right upon instantiated ( a must for all pre v.4.2+ API IIRC ) upon any execution of a panic-case or intentional `defer *.Close()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Did I mis-understood this pattern? Yes, fortunately you did.

ZeroMQ archetypes were defined so as to represent a certain behaviour. As said, `PUSH`-archetype AccessPoint pushes every message "through" all the so far setup communication channels, `PULL`-er AccessPoint pulls anything that has arrived down the line(s) to "it's hands", `PUB`-lisher AccessPoint publishes, `SUB`-scriber AccessPoint subscribes, so as to receive just the messages, that match it's topic-filter(s), but not any other.

As it seems clear, such Archetype "specification" helps build the ZeroMQ smart messaging / signalling infrastructure for our ease of use in [distributed-systems](/questions/tagged/distributed-systems) architectures.

---

```
# subscriber (client.py)
import zmq

ctx        = zmq.Context()
subscriber = ctx.socket( zmq.SUB )
subscriber.connect( 'tcp://127.0.0.1:9091' )
subscriber.setsockopt( zmq.LINGER,    0 )         # ALWAYS:
subscriber.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "" )        # OTHERWISE NOTHING DELIVERED

while True:
    msg = subscriber.recv_string()                # MAY USE .poll() + zmq.NOBLOCK
    print msg
```

---

```
subscriber, _ := zmq4.NewSocket( zmq4.SUB )
subscriber.Connect(             "tcp://127.0.0.1:9090" )
subscriber.SetSubscribe(         filter )                 // SET: <topic-filter>

subscriber.SetLinger(            0 )    //  SAFETY FIRST: PREVENT DEADLOCK
defer subscriber.Close()                //  NOW MAY SAFELY SET:

...
msg, _ := subscriber.Recv( 0 )
```

---

As defined, any right instantiated **`SUB`**-side AccessPoint object has literally zero-chance to know, what will be the choice of what messages are those right ones, so that they ought be "delivered" and what messages are not.

Without this initial piece of knowledge, ZeroMQ designers had a principal choice to **be either** Archetype-policy consistent and let `PUB`-side AccessNode to distribute all the `.send()`-acquired messages only to those `SUB`-side AccessNode(s), that have explicitly requested to receive any such, right via the `zmq.SUBSCRIBE`-mechanics **or** to deliver everything sent from `PUB` also to all so far un-decided `SUB`-s.

The former was a consistent and professional design step from ZeroMQ authors.
The latter would actually mean to violate ZeroMQ own RFC-specification.

The latter choice would be something like if one has just moved to a new apartment, one would hardly expect to find all newspapers and magazines to appear delivered in one's new mailbox from next morning on, would one? But if one subscribes to Boston Globe, the very next morning the fresh release will be at the doorstep as it will remain to be there, until one cancels the subscription or the newspaper went bankrupt or a lack of paper rolls prevented the printing shop from delivering in due time and fashion or a traffic jam in the Big Dig tunnel might have caused troubles for all or just the local delivery some one particular day.

All this is natural and compatible with the Archetype-policy.

<sub>*Intermezzo: <sup>Golang has already bindings to many different API versions</sup>* 

Technology purists will object here, that early API releases ( till some v3.2+ ) actually did technically transport all message-payloads from a `PUB` to all `SUB`-s, as it simplified `PUB`-side workload envelope, but increased transport-class(es) data-flow and `SUB`-side resources / deferred topic-filter processing. Yet all this was hidden from user-code, right by the API horizon of abstraction. So, except of a need to properly scale resources, this was transparent to user. More recent API versions reverted the role of topic-filter processor and let this to now happen on the `PUB`-side. Nevertheless, in both cases, the ZeroMQ RFC specification policy is implemented in such a manner, the `SUB`-side will never deliver ( through the `.recv()`-interface ) a single message, that was not matching the valid, explicit `SUB`-side subscription(s)</sub>

In all cases a `SUB`-side has not yet explicitly set any `zmq.SUBSCRIBE`-instructed topic-filter, **it cannot and will not deliver anything** ( which is both natural and fully-consistent with the ZeroMQ RFC Archetype-policy defined for the `SUB`-type AccessPoint ).

### The Best Next Step:

Always, at least, read the ZeroMQ API documentation, where all details are professionally specified - so at least, one can get a first glimpse on the breath of the smart messaging / signaling framework.

This will not help anyone to start on a green-field and fully-build one's own  complex mental-concept and indepth understanding of how all the things work internally, which is obviously not any API-documentation's ambition, is it? Yet, this will help anyone to refresh or remind about all configurable details, once one has mastered the ZeroMQ internal architecture, as detailed in the source, referred in the next paragraph.

Plus, for anyone, who is indeed interested in [distributed-systems](/questions/tagged/distributed-systems) or just [zeromq](/questions/tagged/zeromq) per-se, it is worth one's time and efforts to always read Pieter HINTJENS' book "Code Connected, Volume 1" ( freely available in pdf ) plus any other of his books on his rich experience on software engineering later, because his many insights into modern computing may and will inspire ( and lot ).

*edit:*

### MWE in GO

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/pebbe/zmq4"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func Listen(subscriber *zmq4.Socket) {
    for {
        s, err := subscriber.Recv(0)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        log.Println("rec", s)
    }
}

func main() {
    publisher, _ := zmq4.NewSocket(zmq4.PUB)
    publisher.SetLinger(0)
    defer publisher.Close()

    publisher.Bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:9092")

    subscriber, _ := zmq4.NewSocket(zmq4.SUB)
    subscriber.SetLinger(0)
    defer subscriber.Close()

    subscriber.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:9092")
    subscriber.SetSubscribe("")

    go Listen(subscriber)
    for _ = range time.Tick(time.Second) {
        publisher.Send("test", 0)
        log.Println("send", "test")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the first time I am starting to understand this issue and possible solutions.

Comment: Welcome, glad you enjoyed the help. BTW, great papers on Deblurring et al.

Comment: Thanks, your answer really helped to ease a cluster version of nvidia-smi https://github.com/PatWie/cluster-smi

Comment: If both performance and ultra-low latency come to your focus, beware that many ( indeed indepth ) performance-motivated socket-options tweaking becomes indispensable. Scaling is another dimension to expect an "attack" against both performance and throughput from. One may grow up to some ~ 64 GPU super-convergent HPC clusters, so worth know about. Do not hesitate to raise such points in due time ( design has to follow certain criteria, if ultra-low latency ought be achieved ). Anyway good luck & stay tuned!